# Filezilla very slow startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filezilla

Having filezilla client in ubuntu, for some days filezilla is taking much time (around 10 minuts) to start only at first time.

After first startup, in next filezilla starts immediately.

Note : I've tried logout from current user and login from `guest user` it works perfecly. filezilla starting as it should be..

What the problem should be ?

Comment: No answers, Comments yet .. ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `strace filezilla` from terminal and see what it gets stuck on.

I have a similar problem where Filezilla stalls attempting to access NFS mounts on start-up. Unmounting them should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Set your local directory to something local instead of a mapped directory before closing it.  Next time it starts it will read that local drive at startup which should be fast.